# iOS Time Stamp computation

Tags: ios, time, timestamp

I would like to know if there are other better time stamp computation in iOS and may i know your opinion about this computation weather there are issues or wrong with this computation.

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate * startDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    int totalSeconds = abs((int)interval);

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    int days = totalSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24);
    int weeks = totalSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    int months = totalSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);
    int years = totalSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4 * 12);
```

Your replies are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: i think NSDateComponents will only return the current date components not the whole total numbers of days, weeks and months. correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate * startDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

unsigned units = (NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|
             NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit);
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:units
                                               fromDate:startDate];

int seconds = dateComponents.second;
int minutes = dateComponents.minute;
int hours   = dateComponents.hour;
int days    = dateComponents.day;
int weeks   = dateComponents.week;
int months  = dateComponents.month;
int years   = dateComponents.year;
```

Comment: i think NSDateComponents will only return the current date components not the whole total numbers of days, weeks and months. correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the NSCalendar class and its method:

```
- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)date
```

For example:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponentes *components = [calendar components: unitFlags fromDate: date];
```

Comment: i think NSDateComponents will only return the current date components not the whole total numbers of days, weeks and months. correct me if im wrong.